# Google search interface icon from url

Tags: android, search

I've got problem. I implemented custom search suggestion like in google tutorial [google custom suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) 
I want add icon to search query from url which is in database. My problem is that SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1 can be only a drawable resource, content, or file URI string. How can I 
add icon from url?

Thanks for help.